# Upgraded from VS2019 to VS2022 and now msbuild throws "target 'Build' does not exist in the project" error

Tags: msbuild

I wrote my small F# library in Visual Studio 2019, using msbuild v16. I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 with msbuild v17. While my solution still builds in Visual
Studio 2022, it does not build from the command line using msbuild, like:

```
msbuild MyLib.sln
```

When I run the msbuild command I get the error:

> MSB4057: The target 'Build' does not exist in the project

I can't figure out why msbuild would succeed when called by Visual Studio, but not from the command line.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?